# Add a condition from a template before applying it

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt, xslt-2.0, apply-templates

I have this code on xslt 2.0.

```
<xsl:template match="results">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="result">
    <xsl:if test="result/publication/@testdate='true'">
    <div class="publication-wrapper">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="result/publication/@testdate='false'">
    <div class="former-publication-wrapper">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <div class="publication publication-label" >None</div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>            
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="result">
  <xsl:variable name="publication-uri" select="publication/@uri" />
  <xsl:variable name="publication-label" select="publication/@label" />
  <xsl:variable name="test" select="publication/@testdate" />
  <div class="publication">
    <div class="publication-label">
      <a href="{ov:getPublicationURL($publication-uri)}"><xsl:value-of select="$publication-label" /></a>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

My xml is built like this from a xquery :

```
<results id="publications">
  <result>
    <publication uri="hello" label="hello world" testdate="false"/>
  </result>
  <result>
    <publication uri="goodbye" label="goodbye world" whitelisted="false" testdate="true"/>
  </result>
</results>
```

I want to display my publications in the div publication-wrapper if $test in the template result is true and in former-publication-wrapper if it's false.

In the <xsl:when test="result"> i have tested several things. With <xsl:when test="result/publication/@test='true'">, i have publications, with something random like <xsl:when test="result/publication/@test='aaa'"> i don't have any publications. So I assume that in my xsl:when i can check if $test exists and its value.
But with this code, i don't have any publications even if i know there are.

Comment: Without seeing the structure of you input XML it's hard to help you.

Comment: @Sebastien i add it, i forgot it thanks

Comment: In your code you have this condition : <xsl:if test="result/publication/@test='true'"> but the attribute name is 'testdate', not 'test' in your sample input.